# Visual Studio C++: will using /MT causes run-time library be linked in multiple times?

Tags: c++, compilation

I understand that `/MT` compiler option causes the application to use the multithread, static version of the run-time library.

Suppose my solution consists main project `PrjMain` as a Win32 console application, and a `PrjLib` compiled as static library, both using `\MT`. Will the CRT be linked into the final `PrjMain.exe` twice -- once by the `PrjMain`, once via `PrjLib` as a static libary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRT will only be linked in once.  Both the main project and the `PrjLib` library will link to the same static CRT, as long as both the project and library are compiled into one binary.

Where problems come from are when mixing a module that uses a static CRT with one that uses the DLL CRT in one binary, or when using multiple binaries (an executable and a DLL) that both use the static library.  In those cases you'll get two copies of the CRT loaded, which can cause problems.